# Flutter keyboardtype: TextInputType.none ignore the input

Tags: flutter, dart

```
TextFormField(
  showCursor: false,
  controller: textController,
  autofocus: false,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
 ),
```

Flutter ***keyboardType: TextInputType.none*** ignore the input instead of the soft keyboard/virtual keyboard.

I want to hide my keyboard and keep it on focus.

Anyone have idea how to solve it?